# Move insert position in Text widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

It seems that the statement:  `MyText.mark_set(INSERT, 'new index')`   modify the insert position for the Text .insert() method but not the insertion position of text typed on keyboard.

In other way,  is there any way to use the .insert() method to insert the equivalent of CTRL-END  key

```
from tkinter import *

def curseur(bidon):
    mytext.mark_set(INSERT, END)

root = Tk()
mytext = Text(root)
mytext.pack()
mytext.insert(INSERT, "Clic in other window, then clic back here (line one)\n")
mytext.insert(INSERT, "Type something on the keyboard\n")
mytext.insert(INSERT, "The typed text must go to the end of the widget\n")
mytext.bind("<FocusIn>", curseur)
root.mainloop()
```

Thank you,

Comment: Actually it should move the cursor. Can you show your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does move both the insert position for the `Text.insert()` method **and** the insertion position of text typed on the keyboard. Turns out you need a little delay so that the normal effect of clicking in the Text widget doesn't override our repositioning of the cursor :)

```
from tkinter import *

def curseur(bidon):
    root.after(50, lambda: mytext.mark_set(INSERT, END))

root = Tk()
mytext = Text(root)
mytext.pack()
mytext.insert(INSERT, "Clic in other window, then clic back here (line one)\n")
mytext.insert(INSERT, "Type something on the keyboard\n")
mytext.insert(INSERT, "The typed text must go to the end of the widget\n")
mytext.bind("<FocusIn>", curseur)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `code`(from tkinter import *

def curseur(bidon):
    mytext.mark_set(INSERT, END)

root = Tk()
mytext = Text(root)
mytext.pack()
mytext.insert(INSERT, "Clic in other window, then clic back here (line one)\n")
mytext.insert(INSERT, "Type something on the keyboard\n")
mytext.insert(INSERT, "The typed text must go to the end of the widget\n")
mytext.bind("<FocusIn>", curseur)
root.mainloop()
)

Comment: sorry, see the answer bellow

Comment: @A.Oumnad: So what doesn't work? When I try your code, the text *does* go to the end of the widget.

Comment: when i clic on other window, and click back again in the text, the typed text go exactly where I cliked

Comment: @A.Oumnad: Now I see your point! There's a way to solve that too. Updated the answer once more :)